# Avoiding interruptions from Luis during waterfall dialog (BotFramework v4)

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-language-understanding

How do I prevent Luis from triggering an intent in Bot Framework v4? E.g., when asking the user a question/using prompt like "what's your name?" or "What's your Zip Code?"

In v3, it can be done this way:

```
var recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(url) 
    .onEnabled(function (context, callback) {
        // LUIS is only ON when there are no tasks pending(e.g. Prompt text) 
        var enabled = context.dialogStack().length === 0; 
        callback(null, enabled); 
    });
```

([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47723611/avoiding-interrupts-during-a-waterfall-dialog))

in v4, here's my recognizer:

```
this.luisRecognizer = new LuisRecognizer({
            applicationId: luisConfig.appId,
            endpoint: luisConfig.getEndpoint(),
            endpointKey: luisConfig.authoringKey
        });
```

I'm thinking I'd need to create this as middleware that checks if a dialog state exists and then disable/re-enable Luis...?

Comment: For now, I'm just making sure that utterances that are triggering unneeded Luis intents are assigned to "None" intent.

Answer (score 0):

In your main dialog (the one you use to recognize LUIS intents) check your context to see if there is any active dialog:

```
async onTurn(context) {
    // Create dialog context.
    const dc = await this.dialogs.createContext(context);
    // By checking the incoming Activity type, the bot only calls LUIS in appropriate cases.
    if (context.activity.type === ActivityTypes.Message) {
        // Normalizes all user's text inputs
        const utterance = context.activity.text.trim().toLowerCase();

        // handle conversation interrupts first
        const interrupted = await this.isTurnInterrupted(dc, utterance);
        if (!interrupted) {
            // Continue the current dialog
            const dialogResult = await dc.continueDialog();

            // If no one has responded,
            if (!dc.context.responded) {
                // Examine results from active dialog
                switch (dialogResult.status) {
                    case DialogTurnStatus.empty:
                        // Call to LUIS recognizer to get intent + entities
                        const results = await this.luisRecognizer.recognize(dc.context);
                        // Since the LuisRecognizer was configured to include the raw results, get the `topScoringIntent` as specified by LUIS.
                        const topIntent = results.luisResult.topScoringIntent;

                        switch (topIntent.intent) {
                            case SMALLTALK_INTENT:
                                return await dc.beginDialog(SmallTalkDialog.Name);
                            ...
                        }
                    case DialogTurnStatus.waiting:
                        // The active dialog is waiting for a response from the user, so do nothing
                        break;
                    case DialogTurnStatus.complete:
                        await dc.endDialog();
                        break;
                    default:
                        await dc.cancelAllDialogs();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    } else if (context.activity.type === ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate &&
        context.activity.recipient.id !== context.activity.membersAdded[0].id) {
        // If the Activity is a ConversationUpdate, send a greeting message to the user.
        await context.sendActivity('¡Hola! ¿En qué puedo ayudarte? ');
    } else if (context.activity.type !== ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate) {
        // Respond to all other Activity types.
        //await context.sendActivity(`[${ context.activity.type }]-type activity detected.`);
        //await this.authDialog.onTurn(context);
    }
    // Save state changes
    await this.conversationState.saveChanges(context);
  }
```

Hope this helps.